# SQL Server: Issue with BETWEEN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT C_SousCategorie as y, Enseigne as x, Count(DISTINCT r.Reference_Produit) as val  
                FROM RawData r, Day d
                WHERE r.DayId = d.DayId
                    AND d.WeekNo BETWEEN MAX(d.WeekNo) AND (MAX(d.WeekNo)-2)
                GROUP BY Enseigne, C_SousCategorie 
                ORDER BY 2, 1 ;
```

The above query gives the following error:

```
Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
```

Is there a better way around? I tried the `IN` clause as well but I get the same error.

Comment: Move that condition into a `having` clause

Comment: I would also recommend breaking the habit of using ordinal position as your ordering conditions. If you change the query you either have to change the where clause or your query returns rows in a different order. Be explicit and name the columns.

Comment: "Old-style" joins have been deprecated since the early nineties. It's time to drop that syntax.

Comment: Once you've fixed that error, there's a logical one here also - `a BETWEEN b AND c` is effectively `a >= b AND a <= c` - if `b` is a higher value than `c`, as here, then no results are possible - it's up to you to ensure that the first value is lower than the second.

Comment: @SeanLange - Didn't you notice he changed meaningful column names to meaningless "x" and "y" -- the whole point of this query seem to be to be as obtuse and hard to support as possible -- the ordinals make perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use an aggregate function (`MAX`) inside a `WHERE` clause. The `WHERE` clause is executed before the `GROUP BY`.

You have to move your `BETWEEN` condition to an `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT C_SousCategorie as y, Enseigne as x, Count(DISTINCT r.Reference_Produit) as val  
FROM RawData r, Day d
WHERE r.DayId = d.DayId
GROUP BY Enseigne, C_SousCategorie 
HAVING d.WeekNo BETWEEN MAX(d.WeekNo) AND (MAX(d.WeekNo)-2)
```

The `HAVING` clause is executed after the `GROUP BY`

You also should avoid using column numbers in your `ORDER BY`, this is dangerous.

Comment: It still doesnt work. If I am using `d.WeekNo` in `HAVING` clause is it not necessary to have it in the `group by` clause?

Comment: The error : `Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Column 'Day.WeekNo' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: The problem might just deeper. Your database engine doesn't know what to do with WeekNo because it is "using itself" (if that make sense). Maybe you should do this query in two steps. One, find the WeekNo you want to look for, then use your query with parameters instead of MAX(WeekNo...

Answer (score 2):

I think your query might be better served with using window functions to get the max week from the `Day` table:

```
SELECT C_SousCategorie as y, Enseigne as x,
       Count(DISTINCT r.Reference_Produit) as val  
FROM RawData r JOIN
     (SELECT d.*, MAX(d.WeekNo) OVER () as maxw
      FROM Day d
     ) d
     ON r.DayId = d.DayId 
WHERE d.WeekNo BETWEEN maxw - 2 AND maxw
GROUP BY Enseigne, C_SousCategorie 
ORDER BY 2, 1 ;
```

Also note that the operands to `between` are in the wrong order.  The smaller number always goes first.

Comment: `SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.` I get this error. I dont see any issues with the syntax though.

Comment: easy, you would have to join on something which would everything whats in the where clause